# Using Terraform, how do I create a VM on Azure that uses an existing managed disk?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have imported a managed disk from a blob with terraform.  Now I just need to create a VM with it (it's an OS disk).  How?

I have:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "MyDisk" {
  name                 = "MyDisk"
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Import"
  storage_account_id   = azurerm_storage_account.temp_storage.id
  source_uri           = "${azurerm_storage_container.images.id}/MyDisk.vhd"
  disk_size_gb         = "32"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

azurerm_linux_virtual_machine doesn't seem to have any way to take this managed disk and make a VM with it.  Anyone know how?

thank you much

Comment: Doublechecking my memory against the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine, the "Notes" confirm this kind of API deprecated behavior in Azure is supported with the deprecated `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource. You would need to use that instead. If that is ok, then I can answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment). Example:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "example" {
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.MyDisk.id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.MyMachine.id
  lun                = "10"
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# <https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine>
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "VoIP-VM"
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.VoIP.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.VoIP.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_F2"
  
  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  # delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${azurerm_managed_disk.MyDisk.name}"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "Attach"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    managed_disk_id = "${azurerm_managed_disk.MyDisk.id}"
    os_type = "linux"
  }
  
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```